# Why is the first line of the file not printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print n number of lines and take away the first 4 characters for each line printed but the first line is not coming up.

Code:

```
def saveLine(ifile,ofile,n):
    '''Prints n number of lines with first 4 spaces gone'''
    infile = open(ifile, 'r')
    outfile = open(ofile, 'w')
    line = infile.readline()
    lines = infile.readlines()

    for i in range(n - 1):
        line = lines[i]
        outfile.write(line[4:])
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: @Barmar Should I just delete that portion then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're skipping the first line because of this:

```
line = infile.readline()
```

That reads the first line of the file. Then when you call `infile.readlines()`, it starts with the second line.

So get rid of that unnecessary statement.

Also, `range(n-1)` should be `range(n)`.